# MySQL trigger to set column to max + 1 not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm having difficulty writing a trigger that sets the rank column to the max rank value plus 1 for a group of user ids.  Maybe the code would be more helpful than my description:

```
CREATE TABLE `saved_listing` (
  `saved_listing_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `listing_id` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `listing_ty` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `notes` text NULL,
  `rank` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `modify_by` int(10) NOT NULL default '1',
  `modify_dt` timestamp NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `create_by` int(10) NOT NULL default '1',
  `create_dt` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `active` enum('Yes','No') NOT NULL default 'No',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`saved_listing_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

Here's my trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_saved_listing BEFORE INSERT ON saved_listing
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.create_dt = NOW();
    SET NEW.rank = (SELECT MAX(rank) + 1 FROM saved_listing WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id);
END
```

Here's the error message I'm getting:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I don't have much experience writing triggers.

MySQL Server version: 5.1.49-3~bpo50+1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is because mysql sees `;` (the delimiter) and breaks the execution of `CREATE TRIGGER`

Try to change to:

```
delimiter |


CREATE TRIGGER ins_saved_listing BEFORE INSERT ON saved_listing
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.create_dt = NOW();
    SET NEW.rank = (SELECT MAX(rank) + 1 FROM saved_listing WHERE user_id = NEW.user_id);
END;

|

delimiter ;
```

Comment: OMG!  I would have NEVER thought of that.  That totally worked and makes complete sense.  Thank you!

Comment: @gurun8: yep ;-) It is not obvious issue, caught it too long ago

Comment: One hour wasted for somehting so simple; the error message from MySQL really doesn't help (why not something like `unexpected end of statement`?)